# J2EE form based login error

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jakarta-ee, authentication, realm

I am starting with J2EE apps and I have an annoying error with the form based login. I can't find any solution, and I don't really know what else can I do. I have decided to ask here and see if you can solve it :).

I am programming with eclipse, I have a MySQL database, and I am using a tomcat server provided by eclipse.

When I run the app, the server works correctly. If I try to enter to any secured area (/*), the app makes me go back to the login page. If I write an incorrect combination, the program detects the error, and sends me a message. When I try to log in with the correct username and password, I get this error message:

```
sep 24, 2015 1:13:27 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm getRoles
GRAVE: Excepción al realizar la autentificación
**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'**
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getRoles(JDBCRealm.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have created the following tables in the database:

```
- users , with 2 fields: username and password.
- user_roles, with 1 field: rolename.
- users_user_roles, with 2 fields: username and rolename.
```

I have added the following code to web.xml file:

```
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/fail_login.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
            <description> accessible by authorised users </description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>These are the roles who have access</description>
            <role-name>usuario</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

and I have changed the realm code in the server.xml like these:

```
Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
      debug="99"
      driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/apou_ddbb?user=apou&amp;password=apouddbbpassword"
      userTable="users" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="rolename"
```

I have followed this guide: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/12/form.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are wrong here.

First, the `JDBCRealm` should probably not be used: it's single-threaded and performance will be terrible should you ever grow beyond you and your immediate family using your web application. Use `DataSourceRealm` instead. This means you'll have to define a `<Resource>` with all your JDBC connection information and then link the `DataSourceRealm` to that `<Resource>`. It's a bit more configuration, but it's much more robust.

Second, you have the wrong table for `userRoleTable`: you want `users_user_roles` instead of `user_roles`. Your `user_roles` table merely contains the list of possible roles -- not the actual mapping of users to roles. I might suggest re-naming `user_roles` to simply `roles` and re-naming `users_user_roles` to `user_roles` to avoid confusion: the replacement table name `roles` suggests that it has nothing to do with users, which is (arguably) the truth.

This is covered in the Tomcat users guide, spread across in several documents:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html#DataSourceRealm
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, now it works properly : )

Comment: I have followed your advices and I have changed the table names. I thought they were asking for the role table, not for the connection table.

Comment: Not many people will use the app at the same time, but I will try to change it. Do you know where can I find a tutorial, or something to help me? Thank you very much again, you have solved my day : )